# Javascript issue | progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I found this here http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/wj9gWh8ulj 
and I was trying to know more about javascript and jquery by applying these codes, but I faced an error with implementing this which is the progress bar and the continue buttons are not functional for some reason that I don't know.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.next').click(function(){
    var nextId = $(this).parents('.tab-pane').next().attr("id");
    $('[href=#'+nextId+']').tab('show');
    return false;
  })

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    //update progress
    var step = $(e.target).data('step');
    var percent = (parseInt(step) / 5) * 100;

    $('.progress-bar').css({width: percent + '%'});
    $('.progress-bar').text("Step " + step + " of 5");
    //e.relatedTarget // previous tab
  })

  $('.first').click(function(){
    $('#myWizard a:first').tab('show')
  })
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" id="myWizard">

<h3>Bootstrap Wizard</h3>

<hr>

<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="5" style="width: 20%;">
Step 1 of 5
</div>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
       <li class="active"><a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" data-step="1">Step 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2">Step 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" data-step="3">Step 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#step4" data-toggle="tab" data-step="4">Step 4</a></li>
       <li><a href="#step5" data-toggle="tab" data-step="5">Step 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="step1">

<div class="well"> 

    <label>Security Question 1</label>
    <select class="form-control input-lg">
      <option value="What was the name of your first pet?">What was the name of your first pet?</option>
      <option value="Where did you first attend school?">Where did you first attend school?</option>
      <option value="What is your mother's maiden name?">What is your mother's maiden name?</option>
      <option value="What is your favorite car model?">What is your favorite car model?</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Enter Response</label>
    <input class="form-control input-lg">

</div>

 <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg next"  href="#">Continue</a>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="step2">
 <div class="well"> 

    <label>Security Question 2</label>
    <select class="form-control  input-lg">
      <option value="What was the name of your first pet?">What was the name of your first pet?</option>
      <option selected="" value="Where did you first attend school?">Where did you first attend school?</option>
      <option value="What is your mother's maiden name?">What is your mother's maiden name?</option>
      <option value="What is your favorite car model?">What is your favorite car model?</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Enter Response</label>
    <input class="form-control  input-lg">

 </div>
 <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#">Continue</a>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="step3">
<div class="well"> <h2>Step 3</h2> Add another step here..</div>
 <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#">Continue</a>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="step4">
<div class="well"> <h2>Step 4</h2> Add another almost done step here..</div>
 <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#">Continue</a>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="step5">
<div class="well"> <h2>Step 5</h2> You're Done!</div>
 <a class="btn btn-success first" href="#">Start over</a>
</div>
</div>

<hr>

<a href="http://www.bootply.com/wj9gWh8ulj">Edit on Bootply</a>

<hr>

</div>



<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->

<!-- js of the slider blugin-->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you seeing the Bootstrap styles properly applied? Are you seeing errors in the browser console?

Comment: I actually solved the issues in the console by actually moving the link of the jQuery to the top of the page rather than at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me: http://codepen.io/wvankuipers/pen/qdxVpw

I guess the problem you are facing is that you try to use jQuery/Bootstrap before it is loaded. To fix this place the Javascript code inside this block:

```
$(function(){ 
     /* Your code here */
});
```

Read more about this here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3

Short version: this will make sure the DOM is fully loaded (and the required JS is loaded) before your code gets executed.

Comment: Yes, now it's working, thank you so much, I'll try to look at the link to better understand the problem. Thank you again